# ASP.NET MVC DataAnnotation Required 1 from 3 property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

I am creating a project using ASP.NET MVC.

My model class looks like this:

```
public class CaseInformation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CaseNumber { get; set; }
    public string RitNumber { get; set; }
    public string ApilNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public double CaseInvolvedRevenue { get; set; }
    public string CaseShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string CaseUpdateStatus { get; set; }

    public CompanyDetails CompanyDetails { get; set; }
    public int CompanyDetailsId { get; set; }
}
```

Here `CaseNumber`, `RitNumber`, `ApilNumber` only 1 is required. I can not put `[Required]` on all of them. How do I do that? Please help.

Comment: If you have custom rules like above, I would suggest you to go for `FluentValidation` instead.. See: https://fluentvalidation.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the [`IValidatableObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject?view=netframework-4.7.2) interface in your `CaseInformation` class itself. Here's what it would look like:

```
public class CaseInformation : IValidatableObject
{
    ...

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext ctx)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CaseNumber) &&
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RitNumber) &&
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ApilNumber))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Your error message here.");
        }
    }
}
```

The `Validate(ValidationContext)` method is called by the framework when performing model validation. Here, we're just checking if all three values are missing and if so, we signal an error by returning a `ValidationResult` with a custom error message.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is, You may implement your own validation attribute like below -

```
public class CaseInfoRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var caseInfo = (CaseInformation) validationContext.ObjectInstance;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(caseInfo.CaseNumber) &&
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(caseInfo.RitNumber) &&
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(caseInfo.ApilNumber))
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Either CaseNumber or RitNumber or ApilNumber is required.");
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;        
    }
}
```

Then use the custom attribute for any one of the field

```
public class CaseInformation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [CaseInfoRequired]
    public string CaseNumber { get; set; }
    public string RitNumber { get; set; }
    public string ApilNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public double CaseInvolvedRevenue { get; set; }
    public string CaseShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string CaseUpdateStatus { get; set; }

    public CompanyDetails CompanyDetails { get; set; }
    public int CompanyDetailsId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add an IsValid() function to your model that returns true/false and append errors to the ModelState.

CaseInformation:

```
public class CaseInformation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CaseNumber { get; set; }
    public string RitNumber { get; set; }
    public string ApilNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public double CaseInvolvedRevenue { get; set; }
    public string CaseShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string CaseUpdateStatus { get; set; }

    public CompanyDetails CompanyDetails { get; set; }
    public int CompanyDetailsId { get; set; }

    public bool IsValid(out IDictionary<string, string> errors)
    {
        errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CaseNumber) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RitNumber) &&
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ApilNumber))
        {
            errors.Add("MyError", "At least one Case, Rit or Apil number is required.");
        }
        return errors.Count == 0;
    }
}
```

And then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(CaseInformation model)
{
    if (!model.IsValid(out var errors))
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> error in errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(error.Key, error.Value);
        }                
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // it worked
    }
    else
    {
        // must be errors
    }
    return View();
}
```

And then in your view:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please fix the below and try again.")
```

Comment: in the controller it says **model** dose not exist current context, do I need to import some library?

Comment: You need to use whatever your model object name is posted back to the controller. I have updated my example to include the controller action.

Comment: your code work perfect, but error message is not showing

Comment: You can either use a validation placeholder object on your view or use the ValidationSummary message. I will update my answer.

Comment: While you _could_ do this, I would advise you to go down a path that uses the built-in framework's approach for model state validation such as that [suggested above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52729269/33969). A more "standard" approach may serve you better when integrating with other components (e.g. error prompts in the UI).